# Discord.js | Welcome Message bug?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I created a code that sends welcome message in "welcome" channel at discord.
But I got a problem, here is the code:

```
client.on(`guildMemberAdd`, member => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(`#ffffff`)
        .setAuthor(member.user.username)
        .setDescription(`DobroDosli na **BalkanTop** server.`)
        .setTitle(`**DobroDosli**`)
        .setImage(`https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/701453845519269978/720234585048350761/logo-gray.png`)
    member.guild.channels.cache.get(`720631185688100867`).send(embed);
})
```

And when user joins, bot sends random welcome messages, like:

First welcome message:
Welcome User.

Second welcome message:
Welcome User2.

But only 1 user joined?

Here is a picture:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You want to have two welcome message? or random

Comment: What do you mean "But only 1 user joined?"

Comment: I don't think you explained this at it should be. I suppose you need to turn off welcome messages in your `guild` settings.

Comment: You might have two `guildMemberAdd` instances, the second embed says the `member.user.username` is the bot's username so something to consider when debugging